# How could I can I refresh my Spannable in android?

Tags: java, android, syntax-highlighting

I want to be able to refresh this Spannable that highlights the text, so that every time one of the phrases listed is typed, it will highlight it. But my problem is that it can only type the phrase once, I have been trying to look for other ways to refresh it or highlight it, then remove that it has been highlighted but nothing that I have tried so far works. From what I can think of this, is that the code for this to Highlight every word that matches the phrases listed, is by doing something **onTextChanged**. But I can't see what.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        //Registered functions
        final String FUNCTION = "function";
        final String ENTITY = "Entity";
        final String PLAYER = "Player";
        final String MODPE = "ModPE";
        final String ZERO = "0";
        final String ONE = "1";
        final String TWO = "2";
        final String THREE = "3";
        final String FOUR = "4";
        final String FIVE = "5";
        final String SIX = "6";
        final String SEVEN = "7";
        final String EIGHT = "8";
        final String NINE = "9";
        final String CPER = "{}";
        final String PER = "()";

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int after){

        }
        //Code for Syntax Highlighting
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //Registered function (to find beginning text)
            int iFUNCTION = s.toString().indexOf(FUNCTION);
            int iENTITY = s.toString().indexOf(ENTITY);
            int iPLAYER = s.toString().indexOf(PLAYER);
            int iMODPE = s.toString().indexOf(MODPE);
            int iZERO = s.toString().indexOf(ZERO);
            int iONE = s.toString().indexOf(ONE);
            int iTWO = s.toString().indexOf(TWO);
            int iTHREE= s.toString().indexOf(THREE);
            int iFOUR = s.toString().indexOf(FOUR);
            int iFIVE = s.toString().indexOf(FIVE);
            int iSIX = s.toString().indexOf(SIX);
            int iSEVEN = s.toString().indexOf(SEVEN);
            int iEIGHT = s.toString().indexOf(EIGHT);
            int iNINE = s.toString().indexOf(NINE);
            int iCPER = s.toString().indexOf(CPER);
            int iPER = s.toString().indexOf(PER);

            if (iFUNCTION >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), iFUNCTION, iFUNCTION + FUNCTION.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iENTITY >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), iENTITY, iENTITY + ENTITY.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iPLAYER >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), iPLAYER, iPLAYER + PLAYER.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iMODPE >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), iMODPE, iMODPE + MODPE.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iZERO >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iZERO, iZERO + ZERO.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iONE >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iONE, iONE + ONE.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iTWO >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iTWO, iTWO + TWO.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iTHREE >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iTHREE, iTHREE + THREE.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iFOUR >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iFOUR, iFOUR + FOUR.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iFIVE >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iFIVE, iFIVE + FIVE.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iSIX >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iSIX, iSIX + SIX.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iSEVEN >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iSEVEN, iSEVEN + SEVEN.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iEIGHT >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iEIGHT, iEIGHT + EIGHT.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iNINE >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), iNINE, iNINE + NINE.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iPER >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), iPER, iPER + PER.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if (iCPER >= 0) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), iCPER, iCPER + CPER.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each one of your checks, you can iterate until you've exhausted all cases of the same type:

eg:

```
...
String string = s.toString();
int lastMatch = 0;
while(lastMatch < string.length() && (iFUNCTION = string.indexOf(FUNCTION, lastMatch)) >= 0){
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), iFUNCTION, iFUNCTION + FUNCTION.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    lastMatch = iFUNCTION + FUNCTION.length(); // add the length since we've already matched it
}
...
```

be sure to reset lastMatch to 0 before using it for the next type.

Obviously, this will also be very inefficient as it will recreate spans for areas that already have spans, you could either implement checks to not recreate spans if one already exists or only create spans in ares of the text that have been edited.

Comment: would this go in onTextChanged though?

Comment: This would be in the afterTextChanged callback, like you have it now.

Comment: what is "last" by the way? Is it supposed to be lastMatch?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been lastMatch, I've edited the answer.

Comment: It still highlights the first word typed and the rest are white.